# Change the default "X" char for filled polygon in gnuplot dumb terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

I need to change the default "X" character that fills the area filled by `filledcurves` in gnuplot dumb terminal. Specifically, I want to use "+" and "-".

Here is the data file:

```
# test-data.dat
# x y1 y2
3 3 26
8 8 65
13 13 4
18 18 32
23 23 85
28 28 86
33 33 92
38 38 46
43 43 59
48 48 56
53 53 11
58 58 9
63 63 23
68 68 33
73 73 27
78 78 3
83 83 59
88 88 23
93 93 53
98 98 32
```

This is sequence of gnuplot commands I'm using:

```
gnuplot
set term dumb ansi256  # enable color
plot "test-data.dat" u 1:2:3 with filledcurves above ls 5,\
"test-data.dat" u 1:2:3 with filledcurves below ls 4
```

And this is the result:
[gnuplot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk70B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that is not currently possible.  As you show, it is possible to change the color (even in the dumb terminal) but not the fill character.

**Possible work-around:**

What is the reason for using the dumb terminal?

I ask because it possible that you could use the sixel terminal instead.  That would give you graphics output back to your xterm if the xterm window is set to vt340 mode.  This gives you the same benefit of plotting back into the same terminal as the stream of commands that is the usual reason for using the dumb terminal.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I'm just using the dumb terminal for fun ascii plots. I will look more into the sixel terminal though. Thanks for the clarification and work-around!